# Find and Replace Any Letters and Everything after with "" Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to change what I have below where it replaces everything after and including the quote with nothing or "", to something like where it replaces any possible letter (A to Z) and after with "" ?  So something like

```
Replace What:="A-Z"*", Replacement:=""
```

I have an issue where fields are concatenating out of an old old system so for example 456P321345134 shows up but I only need the 456 and nothing after.

Maybe it's possible to integrate Is Not(Numeric) somewhere into looking at the string of characters?  It is not always the 3rd character, the letter could be the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc....

Original:

```
Replace What:="""*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
       ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without RegEx something simple like this can do:

```
For i = 97 To 122
  Range("your range here").Replace Chr(i) & "*", "", 2, 1, 0
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub firstNumsOnly()
    Dim i As Long, vals As Variant
    Dim rgx As Object

    Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With Worksheets("sheet4")

        vals = .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2

        With rgx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = False
            .Pattern = "[A-Z]"
            For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
                vals(i, 1) = .Replace(vals(i, 1), ChrW(8203))
                vals(i, 1) = Split(vals(i, 1) & ChrW(8203), ChrW(8203))(0)
            Next i
        End With

        .Cells(1, "A").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The below function should be incorporated into a macro that iterates through each cell in your desired range to process.

Using Regular Expressions (will return `VALUE#` if there are no leading digits.

```
Option Explicit
Function firstNums(S As String)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^\d+" 'Match all digits starting at the beginning of string
    If .test(S) Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        firstNums = MC(0)
    Else
        firstNums = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

If you would prefer to return an entirely blank string, should there be no leading digits, then:

```
Option Explicit
Function firstNums(S As String)
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "(^\d*)\D.*"
    firstNums = .Replace(S, "$1")
End With
End Function
```